# Overriding the run() method to accept a parameter from the command line

Tags: java, file-io, command-line, client-server

I'm trying to search a word (from a file) specified in the command line using client/server. Here is my code, however it displays nothing when the client part is run. To run the server, type `-s <port number> <file.txt>` and for the client, `-c localhost <port number> <word to be searched>` in the command line.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class quotes {
    public static InetAddress host;
    public static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static String target;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if(args[0].equals("-c")){
            Client(args);
            target = args[3];
        }
        else if(args[0].equals("-s")){
            System.out.println("Server");
            Server(args);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void Client(String[] args) throws IOException{
            String hostname = args[1];

            if(hostname.equals("localhost")) host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            else host = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);

            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

            Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            Scanner networkInput = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter networkOutput = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            Scanner userEntry = new Scanner(System.in);

            String response;



                networkOutput.println(target);
                response = networkInput.nextLine();
                while(!response.equals("|")){

                    System.out.println("\n " + response);
                    response = networkInput.nextLine();
                }



    }

    public static void Server(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String file = args[2];
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        do {

            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");


            ClientHandler3 handler = new ClientHandler3(client, file);

            handler.start();    
        }while(true);   


    }
}

    class ClientHandler3 extends Thread {
        private Socket client;
        private Scanner input;
        private PrintWriter output;
        private ArrayList<String> quotes;
        public ClientHandler3(Socket socket, String file) {
            client = socket;
            try {
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); 
                String line = reader.readLine();
                try {
                    int ctr = 0;
                    quotes = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while(line != null){
                        quotes.add(ctr, line);

                        ctr++;
                        line = buffer.readLine();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
                output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public void run() {
            String target;
            String message = "";
                target= args[3];
                for(int i = 0; i<quotes.size(); i++){
                    if(quotes.get(i).toUpperCase().contains(target.toUpperCase())){
                        output.println(quotes.get(i));
                    }
                }
                output.println("|");
            try {
                if (client != null) {
                    System.out.println("Closing down connection...");
                    client.close();
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to disconnect!");
            }
        }
    }
```

(Thanks to Sir JB Nizet for some modifications and advice) I'm having a problem in `target= args[3];` in `class ClientHandler3` because I know it makes no sense in overriding. I'm new in this field of programming and I need your help. Please help me figure things out. Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;

public class quotes {
    public static InetAddress host;
    public static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if(args[0].equals("-c")){
            Client(args);
        }
        else if(args[0].equals("-s")){
            System.out.println("SERVER KA!!!");
            Server(args);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void Client(String[] args) throws IOException
            String hostname = args[1];
            String target, response;
            if(hostname.equals("localhost")) host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            else host = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);

            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            target = args[3];
            Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            Scanner networkInput = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter networkOutput = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            // Set up stream from keyboard entry...
            Scanner userEntry = new Scanner(System.in);

                networkOutput.println(target);
                response = networkInput.nextLine();
                while(!response.equals("|")){
                // Display server's response to user ...
                    System.out.println("\n " + response);
                    response = networkInput.nextLine();
                }   

    }

    public static void Server(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String file = args[2];
        String target = "";
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        do {
            // Wait for client...
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");

            ClientHandler3 handler = new ClientHandler3(client, file, target);

            handler.start();    
        }while(true);   


    }

}

    class ClientHandler3 extends Thread {
        private Socket client;
        private Scanner input;
        private PrintWriter output;
        private ArrayList<String> quotes;
        private String target;
        public ClientHandler3(Socket socket, String file, String target) {

            // Set up reference to associated socket...
            client = socket;
            try {
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                this.target = reader.readLine(); 
                String line = reader.readLine();
                try {
                    int ctr = 0;
                    quotes = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while(line != null){
                        quotes.add(ctr, line);

                        ctr++;
                        line = buffer.readLine();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
                output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public void run() {
            String message = "";

                target= input.nextLine();

                for(int i = 0; i<quotes.size(); i++){
                    if(quotes.get(i).toUpperCase().contains(target.toUpperCase())){
                        output.println(quotes.get(i));
                    }
                }
                output.println("|");


            try {
                if (client != null) {
                    System.out.println("Closing down connection...");
                    client.close();
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to disconnect!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set target as a field of ClientHandler3 so you can use it inside `run()` method.

```
class ClientHandler3 extends Thread {
...
private String target;

...
```

and use:

```
this.target = reader.readLine();
```

just before

```
String line = reader.readLine();
```

line.

Comment: Thank you, sir! But I call `ClientHandler3 handler = new ClientHandler3(client, file, args[3])` in the `server` method. But the `target` should be input from the Client. What can be done to address this problem?

Comment: You need to send it from the client to the server. The server cannot know an argument you used to run the client with.

Comment: I tried to call `Server(args)` from the client but it still gets the original arguments of server. I would be very grateful for you help. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can either give the argument to the server also, or send it from the clien to the server over the opened socket

Comment: Considering your second advice, how can I send it through the socket if the constructor `Socket(InetAddress, int, String)` is undefined? String is the target. :)

Comment: I meant over the socket, as a connection between client and server. You can send it to the server using networkOutput.println(target); and at the server read the first line and use it as the target: String target = reader.readLine(); before String line = reader.readLine();

Comment: So no more `myString`.. Thanks! How do I pass `String target = reader.readLine();` to `run()`?

Comment: Thank you sir! However, nothing is being displayed in the console when the client is run. I edited my question above. Did I do it right? :)

Comment: I think its time for you to debug the error. try printing some values to console so you can decide what is OK and what is not.

Comment: I really thank you for helping me. :) Now, I'm adding `System.out.println("Hello");` to the loops and funny how nothing is being displayed.